# Why am I getting this unexpected keyword argument TypeError?

Tags: python, arguments, keyword-argument

I'm testing some code with `*args` and `**kwargs`, and I wrote a dictionary for the `**kwargs`. For some reason, I'm getting

```py
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        second_test(*args)
    elif kwargs:
        second_test(**kwargs)

def second_test(stringa, integera, floata):
    print("Name: %s, Problems Correct: %d, Points: %f" % (stringa, integera, floata))

profile_1 = ["MyName", 21, 132.00]
func(*profile_1)

profile_1a = {'Name': 'MyName', 'Problems Correct': 21, 'Points': 132.00}
func(**profile_1a)
```

The code starts from `line 44` and ends at `line 57`. This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: second_test() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Name'
```

*I've googled "unexpected keyword argument", but I can never find a definition; only other stackoverflow articles.* What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `second_test` does not accept a keyword argument called `Name`, as per your code. Just follow the flow of your code from the second call to `func(**profile_1a)`.

Comment: In your opinion, what is `**profile_1a`? Meaning: what do you think is happening when you use `**` as prefix to a dictionary?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When passing `kwargs` into a function, it expects to find the exact variable name in the list. If instead your dictionary keys were `stringa`, `integera`, and `floata` the function would work without problem.

So you *either need to change your function variable names* or *change the key names in your dictionary to get this to work*

Answer (score 14):

keyword argument is all of the "unknown/unexpected" *named* argument that being passed by name.

for example, let's define a function with one argument

```py
def func(a):
    print(a)
```

now, if we call this function with an "unexpected" named argument like so

```py
func(b=3) # remember we didn't define b as an argument
```

then we will get a TypeError. However, if we modify the function to accept these "unexpected" named arguments, then we can run the previous code

```py
def func(a, **kwargs):
    print(a)
    print(kwargs["b"]) # now, if we pass an argument 'b' to the function, this will print its value (if we don't, we get a KeyError)

> func(3, b=15)
3
15
```